# why the lines of my html and css files got shuffled in sublime text editor?

Tags: html, css, sublimetext3

I am using sublime text editor for web development coding. Recently when i was editing a code all the lines of file got shuffled like the one in code. this is happened with all of my files even with all the previous html and css files. Any one who can help me to get back to correct sequence. I don't want to do it manually as the file is too large to edit again.

```html
                <div ><input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" class="input"></div>
                <div ><input type="submit" name="login" value="Submit" class="input button"></div>
                <div ><input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" class="input"></div>
            </form>
            <a href="register.html">Sign Up
            <form >
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
        <div class="heading"><h1>Login</h1></div>
        <div>Not a member?
    </div>
    <div class="login-form">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <title>Login</title>
<!DOCTYPE html>
</body>
</head>
</html>
<body>
<head>
<html>
```

Comment: Do you use a Version Control System (VCS) like Git for your code?

Comment: Looks like you used the `sort` command on the content of your file (`Edit > Sort Lines` from the menu, `Sort Lines` from the command palette, and it's also bound to a key as well). In any case, unless you have a backup (such as having your code in a VCS as @Pablo mentioned), you have no choice but to manually fix the file, which is likely very tricky or impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Just `Ctrl+Shift+P` (or `Command+Shift+P` on MacOS) to open the tools pallet, type reindent , and pick Indentation: Reindent Lines .

Comment: no it did not solve my problem code is still distorted

Comment: @YousraFarooq get an extension for your code editor https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode let me know if it works for you.